# Get reference of viewPager2 from child fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I have a fragment which contains a `ViewPager2`, It has 3 child fragments, I want to receive an reference viewpager in child fragment to be able to change `viewPager` programmatically. Since parent fragment which contains viewPager is not activity I can not access the viewPager with findViewById. On another question a usersuggested `val pager = container as ViewPager2` but it's returning null. Can someone help me with this. As seen in code snippets, I am trying to get an reference to viewPager in `BillingFragment` from `OneFragment`.

Please let me know if you need to see `ViewPagerAdapter` code snippet.

**Child fragment**

```
class OneFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_billing, container, false)

        val pager = container as ViewPager2

         // ^^^^^ page is null

        return view;

    }
```

**ViewPager main fragment**

```
class BillingFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_billing_main, container, false)

        setupStepView(view)
        setupViewPager(view)
        setupButtons(view)

        return view
    }

    private fun setupStepView(view: View) {
        view.stepView.state
            // You should specify only stepsNumber or steps array of strings.
            // In case you specify both steps array is chosen.
            .steps(
                listOf(
                    "First Step",
                    "Second Step",
                    "Third Step"
                )
            ) // You should specify only steps number or steps array of strings.
            // In case you specify both steps array is chosen.
            .stepsNumber(3)
            .animationDuration(resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime))
            .commit()

        view.stepView.setOnStepClickListener { position ->
            // viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)
        }

    }

    private fun setupViewPager(view: View) {
       // viewPager = view.viewPager;
        view.viewPager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        view.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(
            object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position)
                    view.stepView.go(position, true)
                    setButtons(position, view)
                }

            }
        )

    }

    private fun setupButtons(view: View) {

        view.backButton.setOnClickListener {
            view.viewPager.setCurrentItem(view.viewPager.currentItem - 1, false)
        }

        view.nextButton.setOnClickListener {
            view.viewPager.setCurrentItem(view.viewPager.currentItem + 1, false)
        }

    }

    private fun setButtons(position: Int, view: View) {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                view.backButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                view.nextButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            1 -> {
                view.backButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.nextButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            2 -> {
                view.backButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.nextButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the child fragment's view in parent fragment is not a good idea. If you want to trigger any action from the fragment. You can follow these steps:

```kotlin
class MyViewPagerAdapter(...) : FragmentStateAdapter(...){
   lsit : List<Fragment>

   fun getItem(position :Int) = list[position]
}

class OneFragment : Fragment(){
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_billing, container, false)

        val position = viewPager2.currentItem
        (adapter.getItem(position) as? BillingFragment)?.

        return view;

    }
}

class BillingFragment : Fragment(){
  override fun onViewCreated(...){
    ...
  }

  // pass the data in the parameter that you want to use or update
  fun updateViewPager(position : Int){
     // perform your actions
     view.viewPager.currentItem = position
  }
}
```

**Alternatives**

1. If you know about `EventBus`, then you can use `EventBus`.
2. The android's default way is to use `BroadcastReceiver`.